# Putting a 2D region plot under a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, regions

I am trying to plot this 3D function over a hexagonal region:

```
a1 = Sqrt[3] {1, 0};
a2 = Sqrt[3] {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
k = {kx, ky};
S = 1 + Exp[I k. a2] + Exp[I k.(a2 - a1)];
EE = Abs[S]
R = 4 Pi/(3 Sqrt[3]);
ep = Plot3D[{EE, -EE}, {kx, ky} \[Element] RegularPolygon[R, 6], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 2]
```

This works fine, but I would also like to draw the region under the 3D graph, something like:

```
bz = Graphics[RegularPolygon[R, 6]];
```

or

```
bz = RegionPlot[RegularPolygon[R, 6]];
```

However, using

```
Show[ep, bz]
```

doesn't work. I have found a few similar questions but they mostly seem to be about contours, I didn't know how to extend this for something as simple as a regular polygon.

Comment: do you want you Polygon flat under the region of 3D !?

Comment: Try This 
p = Graphics3D[Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
region = Graphics3D[Polygon[CirclePoints[R, 6] /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, -3}]];
Show[ep,region]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Ash You are very welcome! Thank you for the accept as well!

Comment: That's nice!  What `AspectRatio` did you use?

Comment: @mjw Thank you! The aspect ratio is inherited from `ep`, which was in the OP's original code; they had set it to $2$.